# Simple CSS/JS concatenation with PHP: Pro's and cons?

Tags: javascript, css, workflow, concatenation, modularity

I always develop remotely, and I usually end up with one big main.css and main.js file. The bigger he projects, the more jumbled up things get. So I've been wanting to split up the .css and .js files for increased modularity. But I wouldn't want to have a ton of http requests with loading all these different files. And excellent software like Codekit on't really work for me given my remote dev workflow.

So I came up with this basic setup:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        <?php
        $css = file_get_contents('css/a.css').
               file_get_contents('css/b.css').
               file_get_contents('css/c.css');
        $css = preg_replace('!/\*[^*]*\*+([^/][^*]*\*+)*/!', '', $css); // remove comments          
        $css = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n", "\t", '  ', '    ', '    '), '', $css); // remove tabs, spaces, newlines, etc.
        echo $css;
        ?>  
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <p>Hello.</body>

    <script>
        <?php
        $js = file_get_contents('js/a.js').
              file_get_contents('js/b.js').
              file_get_contents('js/c.js');
        echo $js;
        ?>  
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

What I like about this approach is the modularity of the files, the single http request (only the html file itself) and the fact that everything happens automatically and without messing with the workflow.

What do you guys think about this?

Answer (score 0):

Splitting big JS and CSS files into multiple files is a good development practise. That being said, here are some pros and cons to your solution to combine them on the fly. You may have already thought of these issues ... but here they are anyway:

Pros:

- Client makes a single request.

Cons:

- Additional server processing.
- You cannot benefit from browser caching. Lets say your HTML page referenced `a.css`, `b.css` and `c.css` all separately. So the page now has to make 3 additional requests to display the page. But, if overnight you changed `a.css`, the next time the visitor came to your webpage they would only have to download `a.css` as the server would return a 304 for `b.css` and `c.css`. The browser would know it does not need to re-download the other two CSS files.
- If you have a second page that uses `a.css` and `b.css`, the browser will again download the CSS a fresh with the new page.

There are ways to optimise how resources are downloaded for a webpage. You can use browser caching as mentioned above. You can also split your resources across subdomains as most browsers have a limit to the number of resources they can download at a time from a single subdomain. You could also create a release process that combines and minifies all your CSS files into one. And do the same for your JS files.

There are probably many other ideas/issues that I haven't thought of. Hope that helps.